# Why Can't NGINX Pass the Response Body of the Upstream Server?

Tags: authentication, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm new to NGINX and I'm currently reading the NGINX documentation about [Authentication based on Subrequest Result](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/), so I checked out the [ngx_upstream_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html)  and noticed that I only could get the upstream response status code (using $upstream_status) or upstream response header field ($upstream_http_name) .... but not the upstream response body.

So say I have a scenario where I have 2 services called Auth service and Post service run on different servers, if I want to make an authenticated request to Pot service, NGINX will forward my request to the Auth service for authentication. And then the Auth service will - for example - decode the JWT token and return userId and put it in the response header instead of response body?

My questions are:
Why can't NGINX pass the response body of the upstream server?
Is the scenario above considered a common way to pass upstream server data?

Comment: Do you mean "parse"?